# vim: Interactive search and replace with perl compatible regular expressions

Tags: perl, vim, replace

According to [this page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Perl_compatible_regular_expressions) you can use perl compatible regular expression with

`:perldo s/pattern/insert/g`.

This works fine.

But, how can I get **interactive** search and replace with PCRE syntax in vim?

Since this does not work with `perldo` I search for a different solution.

Comment: vim regex brings more feature than Perl regex in vim. worth learning

Comment: You mean having the user look at and confirm each replacement? There's no built in functionality like that as far as I know.

Comment: BTW, this isn't PCRE; this is actual Perl code with actual Perl regexes.

Comment: @Kent Neither is a superset of the other, and `:perldo` does more than just Perl regexes.

Comment: Why do you need PCREs? If you're just annoyed with the vim-isms in REs, you can set `magic` or `verymagic`. Then you could still make use of the interactive `c` flag.

Comment: Why I need PCRE? Because I know them very well. I tried to find the official docs for "verymagic", but failed. What does it do?

Comment: @guettli I know PCRE too, perhaps not as good as you, however when I am in vim, I don't miss pcre at all.  verymagic / magic  is just for some escapings. do a `:h magic` you should see.  And the feature you asked, searching with Pcre (e.g. `/` or `?`), I don't think it exists. Moreover, you can do `perldo s/foo/bar/g` it won't set the `/` register, but vim's `:s` does, in some cases it could be very handy,  like to redo the `:s` commands or do further search without typing again. so think about learning vimregex. if you know pcre very well, it's not difficult to you either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Till the current release version of vim, there is no way to do `:s/[perlRegex]/bar/c`

So you are asking for a feature that doesn't exist.

You can do matching with `verymagic`, however it is not Perl Regex compatible flag. It is still using the vimregex engine, just changed the way of escaping regex patterns.

For example, in perl, you can do lookahead/behind `(?<=foo)..., (?=foo), (?!foo)..`, you can use the handy `\K` : `som.*ing\Kwhatever` etc, you cannot use those syntax in vim directly, no matter which 'magic' level you have set. Vim has the same feature, but different syntax:

```
\@=
\@!
\@<=
```

and also the `\zs \ze` are very handy, even more powerful than perl's `\K`.

Vim is an Editor, with vim regex, you can not only do text matching, but also match base on visual selection, cursor position and so on.

If you really need to do complex pattern matching and really need do them in vim, learn vim regex! It is not difficult for you if you "know pcre very well"

Comment: `:help perl-patterns` is a good read for finding the equivalent perl pattern for vim.

Comment: I find this answer to be both obnoxious and very helpful at the same time. Thanks for the "you can not only do text matching, but also match base on visual selection, cursor position and so on". That's great to know and makes me want to learn Vim's regex.  Having said that, a lot of us know the PCRE-like flavors of regex extremely well since they're so well supported by many programming languages. The transition to Vim (and GNU coreutils for that matter!) regex flavors can be a huge annoyance.

Comment: @DaveGauer It is particularly annoying when using vim to code in a language that uses PCRE or very similar (so pretty much every language). Switching back and forth gets old real fast.

Comment: @Z4-tier Ha ha, two years later, I agree. In the meantime, I've actually delved into Vim's regex flavor(s) quite deeply and they're...excellent! As always, it's the _switching_ that sucks.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the closest you can get is:

```
:s/\vfoo/bar/gc
```

Comment: Have a read on Vim's different magic modes: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic

Comment: In general, if you want Perl-like regex you can use very magic mode (\v) in your expressions. I'm sure it's not an exact 1-1 match with Perl, but it's very powerful and I've yet to have it fail me

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to try [eregex plugin](https://github.com/othree/eregex.vim). It maps perl compatible regular expressions to VIM regex syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `s/pattern/insert/g` is a perl command, not a Vim command using a perl-compatible regular expression syntax.

If perl doesn't have an equivalent of Vim's `/c` flag you will need to find an alternate method like… writing an actual perl script.

Comment: I prefer an interactive solution.

Comment: You can't have that with `:perldo` alone.

Comment: I added a note to the question: Since this does not work with `perldo` I search for a different solution

Comment: No. You should remove the bounty on this question and ask another one (with a bounty if you want).

Comment: @romaini The title if this question was "vim: Interactive search and replace with perl compatible regular expressions" since the very beginning. Please explain why I should ask another question.

Comment: The title if the question was "vim: Interactive search and replace with perl compatible regular expressions" since the beginning. I don't care about the name of the command. It can be "perldo", "perlfoo" or "perlbarf". Please explain why I should ask a new question. I am curious.

Comment: The title is generic, the question itself is not. You asked about `:perldo` and you got your answer. Now, armed with the knowledge that `:perldo` won't work — at least on its own — you can ask another, more generic question.